Suppress repeating values in report based on SQL Query in Enterprise Architect
I'm using a SQL query in a Template Fragment to report from EA. The query contains a join, and I would like to suppress repeating values from the inner table in the join. Does the EA template fragment provide for that, and how does it work?
Currently I get a table box for every single row in the result set.  I would like to combine all rows corresponding to 1 row from the inner table together in one table row, and to show the columns from the inner table just once, not for every row from the outer table.
